# problem with reading path uploading a file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, upload

I started some time ago a project with angular and nodejs with mongodb. but I updated nodejs at latest version.

when I upload a file a image the file is inserted into the backend but I can not get the full path of the file. (I tested with postman).

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path') at uploadAvatar (/var/www/html/room/room-backend/controllers/room.js:749:36)
```

the line 749 is var file = `req.files.file0.path;`

I using in the controller room.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
```

but maybe nodejs 18 is using other logic to work with path and files.

I am triying to figure out in the documentation the issue. but without results.

roomsjs routes

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');

var RoomController = require('../controllers/room');

var router = express.Router();
var md_auth = require('../middlewares/authenticated');

var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var md_upload = multipart({ uploadDir: './uploads/rooms' });



// Rutas de usuarios
router.post('/save', RoomController.save);
router.put('/update', md_auth.authenticated, RoomController.update);
router.put('/updateimage1', RoomController.updateImage1);
router.post('/saveimg', RoomController.saveImg);
//router.post('/saveimg/:id/:image1/', RoomController.saveImg);
router.post('/upload-avatar',  md_upload, RoomController.uploadAvatar);
// //router.post('/upload-avatar', [md_auth.authenticated, md_upload], AdminController.uploadAvatar);
router.get('/avatar/:fileName', RoomController.avatar);
//router.get('/avatar2/:image2', RoomController.avatar2);
// router.delete('/book/:id', md_auth.authenticated, AdminController.delete);
router.delete('/delete-avatar/:fileName', RoomController.deleteAvatar);
router.get('/rooms/:page', RoomController.getRooms);
router.get('/roomsEs/:page', RoomController.getRoomsEs);
router.get('/roomsfull/:page', RoomController.getRoomsFull);
// //router.get('/books/', AdminController.getBooks);
router.get('/room/:roomId', RoomController.getRoom);
router.delete('/delete/:roomid', md_auth.authenticated, RoomController.delete);
// router.get('/search/:search', AdminController.search);
```

Comment: It's probably related to how `connect-multiparty` is attaching the upload to the `req` object.  Validate what `req.files` contains before trying to access the nested objects.  If it's empty, but your upload is the same, maybe it has an issue on node 18?

Comment: I can not validate what re.files constains. the file is uploaded to the folder but I can not get the filename with the full path

Comment: req.files is empty